# spectral centroid of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, wav

I have a `.wav` file (in this example it is called "piano2.wav").

i want to find the spectral centroid of in python.

using the code from another post on here i have this function :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

def spectral_centroid(x, samplerate=44100):
    magnitudes = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(x))
    length = len(x)
    freqs = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(length, 1.0/samplerate)[:length//2+1])
    return np.sum(magnitudes*freqs) / np.sum(magnitudes)
```

I read the wav file using scipy.io.wavfile.read into a numpy array, and then try to feed it into the above function

```
a=read("piano2.wav")
print("Spectral centroid is " + spectral_centroid(a[1]))
```

This is the error that I get

```
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print("Spectral centroid is " + spectral_centroid(a[1]))
  File "test.py", line 8, in spectral_centroid
    return np.sum(magnitudes*freqs) / np.sum(magnitudes) 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (302712,2) (151357,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to multiply arrays of different shapes (`magnitudes` and `freqs`):

```
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.arange(5)
print(a*b)
```

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (5,)

This could help:

```
def spectral_centroid(x, samplerate=44100):
    magnitudes = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(x))
    length = len(x)
    freqs = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(length, 1.0/samplerate)[:length//2+1])
    magnitudes = magnitudes[:length//2+1]
    return np.sum(magnitudes*freqs) / np.sum(magnitudes)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (151357,2) (151357,)

Comment: Try `magnitudes*freqs[:, None]`

Comment: This is starting to look like basic debugging help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm new to python (coming from java, I find the syntax to be a little confusing). This code is for a school project albeit probably above my level. Thank you though, it looks like it is working now @MadPhysicist